# How to detect changes in data of API after every 10 min?

Tags: node.js, rest, get

I want to build a web site using node.js that will keep eye on change in data of API and it will send email if change is detected.

How to query on API every 10 min and detect for changes?

Comment: You would typically use `setInterval()` to call some function repeatedly at some time interval.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval works only when the client is open. my advice to you is [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)
that you use the package.

Comment: will it work on server after deploying ? 
it should check for the change after every 5 min

Comment: what API data are you talking about? Is it the request? Or is it the data in the database?

Comment: it is the request using GET